# what is the best way to position elements inside of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a chatroom I built in node js, HTML, and CSS and I am appending the messages to a div and styling the messages with css so my question is what is the best way to position these elements like the profile picture, the name, date, and message

here is my current style I do not feel good about these because if you look at them in dev tools you will see that the span or whatever is much bigger or smaller than the actual element is supposed to be I think

[image: example1]

[image: example 2]

[here](http://niknet.ddns.net:8080) is the link to my site so you can view the dev tools

here is what I have tried I like the look but this bothers me and leads me to think that there will be graphical bugs on other devices

```
#message-container {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: black;
}

.chat-room-profilePic img {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.chat-room-message {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    left: 52px;
    top: 10px;
}

.chat-room-date {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 12px;
    top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: cadetblue;
}

.message-info {
    position: relative;
    top: -32px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

can somone please help me or tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question but I would recommend learning how to use CSS flexbox. Flexbox is a spec for dynamic layouts. [Stackoverflow documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/445/flexible-box-layout-flexbox#t=201702220104341168087) and [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) has a decent tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, you can definitely do everything without flex-box:

html

```
<article class='user'>
    <figure class='avatar'>
        <img src='http://placehold.it/400x400' alt='' />
    </figure>
    <div class='info'>
        <div class='name'>Account name</div>
        <div class='date'>12/12/2012</div>
        <div class='time'>4:4500 PM</div>
        <div class='message'>Hello Mr Account name</div>
    </div>
</article>
```

styles

```
responsive-image()
    img
        display: block
        width: 100%
        height: auto

.user
    display: inline-block
    padding: .5rem
    .avatar, .info
        display: inline-block
        vertical-align: middle
    .avatar
        responsive-image()
        max-width: 50px
        border-radius: 50%
        overflow: hidden
    .info
        .name, .date, .time
            display: inline-block
            vertical-align: middle
```

Here's is a CodePen with both:  http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/ryBBdy

I love flex-box, but it's not always the best for every situation.

Comment: im sorry i am kinda confused on how to use this this isn't regular css

Comment: Opps. Just imagine there are brackets around everything. You can also look at the codepen - and in the upper right corner of the CSS panel, there is a button to show you the compiled CSS. : )

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using flexbox.

```css
#message-container {
  max-width: 320px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
img {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.column {
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: .35em 0 0;
}
.chat-room-username-server {
  color: #09c;
}
.chat-room-date {
  font-size: .8em;
  color: turquoise;
}
.message-info {
  margin: 0 0 .25em;
}
.chat-room-message {
  line-height: 1.4;
}
```

```html
<div id="message-container" class="flex parent">
  <span class="chat-room-profilePic">
    <img src="http://chat.billischill.ga:8080/profiles/userPictures/SERVER.png">
  </span>
  <span id="chat-room-message" class="chatroom-message flex column">
    <span class="message-info">
      <span class="chat-room-username-server">SERVER:</span>
      <span class="chat-room-date ">2/21/2017, 5:06:28 PM</span>
    </span>
    <span class="chat-room-message ">you have connected to General-Chat lorem ipsum sit dolor you have connected to General-Chat lorem ipsum sit dolor</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that flexbox doesn't work on IE9 and below, so if you need to support IE9 be sure to test it there to ensure that it degrades gracefully.